# How to permanently change the default gateway on Windows

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-xp, ip, gateway

I'm trying to change default gateway in both Windows 7 and Windows XP by deleting previous gateway and assigning a new one.

After reboot the changes are reverted and I get the deleted gateway assigned.

My commands in cmd were:

```
route.exe delete 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 [old_ip_gatway]
route.exe add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 [new_ip-gateway]
```

I've tried also the same command but with `-p` before `delete` or `add`, without success.

Any ideas why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The default gateway is assigned by your DHCP server (normally your router).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if things have changed with Windows 7 but on XP you could just do something like this.

```
route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

or

```
netsh interface ipv4 set route 0.0.0.0/0 "Local Area Connection" 192.168.1.1
```

netsh is the right way - doing it with a route add will require you to re-add the route each time you reboot the OS
or this

```
netsh int ip set address "Local Area Connection" address=192.168.1.64 mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=192.168.1.1
```

You have to specify every field (address, mask and gateway). Otherwise they will be reset.

Comment: Can you please explain : 1. The difference between the last two `netsh` commands?
2. Its seems that the third isn't equivalent to the first, can you explain why?

Comment: Here you go, your full guide to netsh commands from Microsoft :) [link]https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490943.aspx [/link]

Comment: 0.0.0.0/32??? Shure?